# POS (Point of Sale) software / system for small shop - Free or Low Cost

Tags: windows

Looking for POS software to run on Windows (ideally).  Its for the outlet of a not-for-profit organisation, hence the need to keep costs low (free / open source ideal).  Needs facility to sync with the cloud to combine a few (3) such outlets (poss utilizing something like Dropbox?).  Needs to handle varying VAT rates, stock control and multiple customer accounts.  Can anybody suggest a suitable solution,

Comment: You need to inform the community as to where you are located in order for good advice to be given.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best POS system with open source I recommended to use [unicenta](https://unicenta.com/)